# Array Index Out Of Bounds Error When Computing Generalized Harmonic Numbers

Tags: java, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

Beginner to java. Trying to make code that takes 2 command line arguments (n, r) and uses a for loop to compute the nth generalized harmonic number of order r.

I keep getting the error "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" and I have no idea why. In the loop, I have tried i < n and i<=n and keep getting the same result.

Here is the code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        float sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            sum += 1 / Math.pow(i, r);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Edit: I am running the program from the mac command line and it's not letting me enter arguments at all. Sorry if this is missing something very obvious.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the way you're running your program.

Comment: Only the command line could give that result of an `ArrayInexOutOfBoundsException` from what I'm seeing here. Are you sure that the arguments you are using to call it are really reaching the `args`? `java -cp myClass 5 3`

Comment: The only place you're accessing an array is when you get n and r. It appears you're not providing the arguments correctly.

Comment: Be aware questions need to include the specific error, and need to include instructions to reproduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the error has nothing to do with your harmonic numbers. Input values are the problem. If you look into the exception carefully you will see that it is thrown at the line where you extract the parameters from the command line arguments `args[N]`. For that is the only place where you operate with arrays in your code.

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.out.println("The program requires 2 arguments. You provided " + args.length);
        return;
    }
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int r = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sum += 1 / Math.pow(i, r);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

You will see that your arguments are somehow not provided. Check how do you run your program.

Comment: Thank you! I actually was inputting my arguments wrong, I'm sorry for such a silly mistake.

Comment: @silly_bear_11 no problem, it always happens :) If my answer was helpful, I'd appreciate if you'd smack this green checkbox that you accepted it :) thanks in advance!

Comment: Just clicked the checkmark, and now it says on my end that it's accepted. Thanks again!